# Web Appbuilder Widget refreshes and changes popup visibility to hidden

Tags: javascript, popup, arcgis-web-appbuilder, css

I am trying to update an app used from Web Appbuilder 1.2 to WAB 2.11.  I cannot get the nexrad widget/map to behave the same in the newer version of WAB.  In 1.2, the widget refreshes (1,2,5,or 10 second intervals).  In 2.11, every time the Widget refreshes, my layer popups (when I click a feature on the map) disappear.  Using developer tools, the styles read as follows:

```
.esriPopupHidden, 
.esriPopupHidden * {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity:  0;
```

I can uncheck these with the developer tools and the popup is visible again.  I tried adding

```
.esriPopupHidden, 
.esriPopupHidden * {
    visibility: visible !important;
    opacity:  1 !important;
```

to the `styles.css` file but that doesn't seem to work.  Is there somewhere in the *CSS* or *JS* where I need to make a change to decouple these actions (Nexrad refreshes and layer popups)?  There is no obvious location with the `div id` or an `esri.css` file.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Located in the pathway `jimu.js/LayerInfos/LayerInfo.js` is the following code:

```
    _isShowInMapChanged: function() {
      var showInMapChanged = false;
      var newIsShowInMap = this.isShowInMap();
      if(newIsShowInMap === false) {
        //hide map's popup.
        this.map.infoWindow.hide();
      }
      if (this._oldIsShowInMap !== newIsShowInMap) {
        // update _oldIsShowInMap
        this._oldIsShowInMap = newIsShowInMap;
        showInMapChanged = true;
      }
      return showInMapChanged;
    },
```

I commented out the `infoWindow.hide()` section as follows:

```
    _isShowInMapChanged: function() {
      var showInMapChanged = false;
      var newIsShowInMap = this.isShowInMap();
      // if(newIsShowInMap === false) {
      //   //hide map's popup.
      //   this.map.infoWindow.hide();
      // }
      if (this._oldIsShowInMap !== newIsShowInMap) {
        // update _oldIsShowInMap
        this._oldIsShowInMap = newIsShowInMap;
        showInMapChanged = true;
      }
      return showInMapChanged;
    },
```

and that works!